# I get random characters when i start eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

this :

[image]

I have this error that makes the code unreadable.

After i get an error the issuse disappears and the code come back normal.
I can't code with this, is very annoying, can someone help me?

Comment: I think this should be posted as a [bug report](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/) for Eclipse.

Comment: yeah, but i hope someone have the same issue, and can explain me how to solve

Comment: Is there something special about the line where the problem starts?

Comment: When you've submitted the bug report, you may want to link to it in the question.

Comment: no, the line when stars the problem is completely random

Comment: Which text file encoding? Which Eclipse version? Which additional plug-ins do you use?

Comment: standard Eclipse 4.5.2 , i use tomcat 6 and JBoss 6.4, for some reason, but nothing dangerous

Comment: i have standard text file encoding(CP1252) but the problem is still here